# Show balance in PHP using API?

Tags: php

I'm trying to show SMS balance using an API in a PHP page.
What am I missing to simplify this? (The API is working fine directly):

```
public function show_sms_credits() {


    if ( false === ( $my_query = get_transient( 'available_sms_credits' ) ) ) {

        $api_key    = get_option( 'wc_api_key', true );
        $api_token  = get_option( 'wc_api_token', true );

        if( empty ( $api_key ) || empty( $api_token ) ){
            return;
        }

        $url = 'http://mywebsite.com/api/';

        $response = wp_remote_get("{$this->url}GetBalance?User={$this->api_key}&Password={$this->api_token}");

        if( ! is_wp_error( $response ) && 200 == wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) ) {
            $body = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
            set_transient( 'available_sms_credits', $body->sms_credits, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
        }
    }

    $sms_credits = get_transient( 'available_sms_credits' );

    }
}
<p> SMS Balance: <?php echo 'available_sms_credits': ?> </p>
```

Comment: Just asking as this looks like an extremely well written code with 2 major items omitted....is this for a project for an education institution?

Comment: Just editing some code for personal use

Comment: Just a quick guess - what about: `<p> SMS Balance: <?php echo $sms_credits; ?> </p>`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you use this syntax

```
$url = 'http://mywebsite.com/api/';
```

You should simply use

```
$response = wp_remote_get("{$url}GetBalance?User={$api_key}&Password={$api_token}");
```

Because you've only assigned local variables, not assignments to the current object itself. If you needed to add the URL as a property against your object you'd have use `$this` like...

```
$this->url = 'http://mywebsite.com/api/';
```

Also your're not doing anything with `$sms_credits`